# Ubuntu Hardy Postfix: Configuration problem?

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, postfix, ubuntu-8.04

I've installed posfix and my web app is now successfully sending mails.

However, the mails have the following text at the start of each mail:

Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 
From: Application  
Message-Id: <20090910093629.0025C10467B@mail.application.com>
Date: Thu, 10 Sep 2009 09:36:28 +0000 (UTC)

Is this a configuration problem and if so does anyone know how I can resolve it?

Regards,
Fiona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a problem with your web app, most likely.  What happens if you try to send email from the command line (either using the simple "Mail" client or just by telnetting to port 25 and issuing SMTP commands).  If they don't have this weird header (and I'm pretty sure they won't), then postfix is fine, and you need to figure out what's wrong with your web app.

Comment: Hi Paul,

You were right.. just sent a mail from the command line.. and it doesn't have the weird header.. will contact my developers. (They told me it was an issue with the installation!) 

Many thanks for your help
Fiona

Comment: Fiona, the standard way to say thanks on this site is via upvotes or by accepting the answer, or both.

Comment: Ok.. I've been informed that the reason issuing a mail from the command line works fine is because it is of type text. However the mails I'm sending are of type HTML. Is there something else I need to check to get rid of the message?

Regards,
Fiona

Comment: It looks like your web app is putting header information into the body of the message instead of the header.  Tell whoever wrote your web app to look for an extraneous carriage return or new-line before the "Content-type" line.

Comment: Had extraneous carriage returns. Emails are sending beautifully now! Thanks.